Persistant Location Based Notifications Swift
I have cobbled together for my first swift app the following code, If i am at the location coordinates with the app closed when the notification event is fired the notification is delivered correctly, in every other scenario it fails, i have Location Updates and Background Fetch enabled in the Background Modes section.
Any pointers hugely appreciated, thank you.
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.website.uk")!)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onAppear {
                locationManager.requestPermissions()
            }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

@main
struct NotificationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func triggerNotification(_ password: String)
    {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "My First Notification"
        content.body = password
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.subtitle = "Hello World"
        content.userInfo = ["value": "Data with local notification"]
        
        let fireDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date().addingTimeInterval(10))
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: fireDate, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        center.add(request)
        {
            (error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error in local notification") ")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region.identifier == "LOC1"
        {
            triggerNotification("Boo: " + Date().formatted())
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region.identifier == "LOC1"
        {
            //reset the region state
            locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to monitor region: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location manager failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func requestPermissions() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Notification permission granted.")
                
                //self.triggerNotification("Test")
                
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Notification permission denied with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        //Setup Geofence
        let locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.1234, longitude: -1.2345)
        let geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: locationCoordinates, radius: 500, identifier: "LOC1")
        geofenceRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        geofenceRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)
    }
}   


Can you elaborate on "in every other scenario" as the only time I can see that a notification would be generated is when you entered the geofenced region, which is what you imply is happening.  Also, is the second notifyOnEntry meant to be a notifyOnExit?

So if i am not in the geofenced area and i open the app and 30 mins later enter the geofenced area the notification doesnt appear.
If i am in the geofenced area, open the app, dismiss the notification and leave and reenter the geofenced area the notification doesnt reappear.
The notifyOnExit was an attempt to reset the notification but it doesnt work.

You will want always authentication to let geofence monitoring work in the background.
